# awk: match fields and insert constant values into matrix

Tags: awk

I will like to manipulate two files (t.dat and b.dat) using awk. I made some progress but am stock at step5 in which I want to match $1,$2 of step4 (tempb_a2.dat) with b.dat and write $3 of step4 into b.dat to produce out.dat. This is my code:

```
    awk '!($3 <= -2000)' OFS="\t" t.dat > t_a2.dat      # step1
    awk '$3 >= -2000 {$3="100000"}1' t.dat > t_b2.dat   # step2
    awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1,$2]; next} ($1,$2) in a'  t_a2.dat b.dat > b_a2.dat  # step3
    awk '$3 > 0 {$3="100000"}1' b_a2.dat > tempb_a2.dat # ste4
                                    # step5: match $1,$2 of step4 with b.dat and replace $3 of b.dat with constant values
==> tempb_a2.dat <==
3173.31022404 0.999881782111 100000
3175.31041958 0.999881782111 100000
3176.31051735 0.999881782111 100000
3177.31061512 0.999881782111 100000
3179.31081066 0.999881782111 100000
3180.31090843 0.999881782111 100000
3182.31110397 0.999881782111 100000

==> b.dat <==
3173.31022404 0.999881782111 485.86
3174.31032181 0.999881782111 486.74
3175.31041958 0.999881782111 487.45
3176.31051735 0.999881782111 487.97
3177.31061512 0.999881782111 488.29
3178.31071289 0.999881782111 488.39
3179.31081066 0.999881782111 488.25
3180.31090843 0.999881782111 487.82
3181.3110062 0.999881782111 487.06
3182.31110397 0.999881782111 486.13

==> out.dat <==
3173.31022404 0.999881782111 100000
3174.31032181 0.999881782111 486.74
3175.31041958 0.999881782111 100000
3176.31051735 0.999881782111 100000
3177.31061512 0.999881782111 100000
3178.31071289 0.999881782111 488.39
3179.31081066 0.999881782111 100000
3180.31090843 0.999881782111 100000
3181.3110062 0.999881782111 487.06
3182.31110397 0.999881782111 100000

========================================
==> t.dat <==
3173.31022404 0.999881782111 -1832.86
3174.31032181 0.999881782111 -4097.18
3175.31041958 0.999881782111 -297.84
3176.31051735 0.999881782111 NaN
3177.31061512 0.999881782111 -1926.67
3178.31071289 0.999881782111 -4927.53
3179.31081066 0.999881782111 NaN
3180.31090843 0.999881782111 -1900.99
3181.3110062 0.999881782111 -4174.76
3182.31110397 0.999881782111 -1041.73
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, we could do this in single `awk` itself if you could let us know in plain English about the steps which you want to do, it will be good for us to understand your problem then, cheers.

Comment: Thanks RavinderSingh13, I want to replace NaN and values above -2000 (in t.dat) with constant (100000) so as to retain the dimension. I also want to understand how it works.

Comment: You've described **how** you want to do something but not **what** it is you want to do. If you expect us to read your code to figure it out then YMMV so best to add a paragraph to your question clarifying **what** it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** OP is asking 2nd question about 2 files so adding that too now.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2]=$NF;next} {print $1,$2,a[$1,$2]?a[$1,$2]:$NF}' tempb_a2.dat b.dat > out.dat
```

---

As per your comment what I got is you need to change those last fields whose values are either `NaN` or greater than `-2000` if this is the case then following may help you.

```
awk '$NF=="NaN" || $NF>-2000{$NF=100000} 1' t.dat
```

***Explanation:***

`$NF=="NaN" || $NF>-2000`: Checking condition here if last field($NF) is either string `NaN` or greater than `-2000` then do following.

`$NF=100000`: Assigning last field's value to `100000` for current line.

`1`: Mentioning `1` here, `awk` works on method of `condition` then `action` so by mentioning `1` making condition TRUE and not mentioning any action so by default print of current line will happen.

`Input_file`: Mentioning Input_file name here which we need to pass through to `awk`.

Comment: Thanks, that works correctly. what purpose does "1" serve please?  How can I substitute $3 of ==> tempb_a2.dat <== into $3 of ==> b.dat <==, after matching $1, $2?

Comment: @geomarine, first thing, I have added explanation to my code too, please check the meaning of `1` over there. 2nd thing try to encourage people by up-voting their efforts. 3rd- your other question is NOT clear so please mention it in your question and do let me know then, cheers.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I want to know how to match tempb_a2.dat and b.dat, write out.dat.

Comment: Yes,  match tempb_a2.dat and b.dat, write out.dat

Comment: @geomarine, please do let me know if this helped you?